# Importing a library built with Rollup and typescript causing errors with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, rollup

**Scenario**

Built a react component library using Rollup, Typescript and MUI.   Everything works fine in a live environment, however, when trying to use jest and @testing-library it fails with the following error

`Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

I checked the following

- exports/imports are all done properly(AFIK)
- using proper syntax to pass icons to Mui Button Components
- I tried using named exports in rollup config
- Testing the library internally, i.e. in the library project, the same tests runs fine(not transpiled)
- Tried adding the libraries to transformIgnorePatterns
- Running jest tests work fine with MUI in the client app, as long as the custom library is not imported

**Here is the rollup.config for the library**

```
import { babel } from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";
import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import terser from "@rollup/plugin-terser";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import pkg from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" };

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: pkg.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: pkg.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    external: [
      "react",
      "react-dom",
      "@mui/styles",
      "@mui/material",
      "@mui/icons-material",
      "@emotion/styled",
      "@emotion/react",
    ],
    plugins: [
      json(),
      nodeResolve(),
      commonjs(),
      postcss(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "../../tsconfig.json" }),
      babel({
        exclude: "node_modules/**",
        babelrc: false,
        presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { modules: false }], "@babel/preset-react"],
      }),
      terser(),
    ],
  },
];
```

**Tsconfig of library**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "ESNext" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
    "module": "ESNext" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
    "moduleResolution": "Node" /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */,
    "resolveJsonModule": true /* Enable importing .json files. */,
    "allowJs": true /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */,
    "declaration": true /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */,
    "declarationMap": true /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */,
    "outDir": "./dts" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["./src/__tests__/**/*"]
}
```

**Jest config of client app**

```
export default {
  clearMocks: true,

  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'mjs', 'cjs', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'json', 'node'],

  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|scss)$': '<rootDir>/empty-module.js',
  },
  verbose: true,

  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
};
```